# Do the Vedas contain all knowledge?

Tags: vedas, knowledge

I do know of the verse within Manusmṛti (2.7) which says that the Vedas embodies all knowledge but I was wondering if any other texts (like the four Vedas themselves or the Puranas etc.) also assert the Vedas containing all knowledge.

Comment: it is said about Mahabharata that "O great man, you will come across whatever is written in this holy text about the four pursuits (purusharthas), that is Righteousness (Dharma), wealth (artha), desire (kama) and the Final Liberation (Moksha) in all other texts and whatever is not given here will not be found anywhere." @rajam

Comment: could you please link to the Manusmriti verse? @rajam ?

Comment: @S K here: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145580.html

Comment: @S K where is the particular verse saying that? (About the Mahabharata talking about the four pursuits etc.)

Comment: Wow - Manusmriti says that?  re: Mahabharata, my source says  "It is a compilation of the historical events of the ancient period. The praise of the Mahabharat sung at its beginnng is in a way befitting it. It goes thus –

धर्मे चार्थे च कामे च मोक्षे च पुरुषर्षभ ।
यदेहास्‍ति तदन्‍यत्र यन्‍नेहास्‍ति न तत्‍क्‍वचित्‌ । "    @rajam

Comment: @S K I couldn't quite understand your reference so could you link it or give source verse? And yes I too was surprised when the Manusmṛti said that (but not that much)